# Yom HaKaseh - Rosh HaShanah

Tags: commentaries, tehilim-psalms, rosh-hashanah-new-year, rosh-chodesh-new-month

Is it true that Rosh HaShanah is also called Yom HaKeseh, meaning “The Day of the Hiding” or “the Hidden Day.” I noticed that it’s called this way because of Tehillim 81. Is it true it’s also called this way because it’s concealed as to when it starts and that it can only start when the moon begins to reflect again?

I find this interesting because somewhat our own wrongdoings and sins are consealed, but during this period from Rosh HaShanah till Yom Kippur we’re quite reflective.

Comment: There are a handful of references to Rosh Hashana as "Keiseh" in the Selichot for Erev Rosh Hashana

Comment: We refer to it by that name in kidsush,...bakeseh yom chageinu

Comment: @Levi You wrote, "I noticed that it’s called this way because of Tehillim 81" - can you source this to a pshat reading from the Tanach, please? For example, I already checked the chabad rashi commentary on "Tehillim 81", and chabad rashi does not support the word "hidden" but "appointed": https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16302/showrashi/true

Comment: @ninamag If I remember correctly I found it in a commentary somewhere, it was refering to Rosh HaShanah 8b, you can look it up in Sefaria.

Answer (score 1):

[The Talmud (Rosh Hashana 8a, 34a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.8a.17-8b.1?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) states:

> תקעו בחדש שופר בכסה ליום חגנו איזהו חג שהחדש מתכסה בו הוי אומר זה ר"ה
>
> Which is the Festival day on which the moon is covered, i.e., hidden?
> You must say that this is Rosh HaShana, which is the only Festival
> that occurs at the beginning of a month, when the moon cannot be seen. (Sefaria)

It refers to Rosh Hashana because it occurs **before** the moon begins to reflect.

Comment: To which pshat reading from the Tanach does this Talmud passage sourced? I already checked the chabad rashi commentary on "Tehillim 81", and chabad rashi does not support the word "hidden" but "appointed": https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16302/showrashi/true

Comment: @ninamag I guess there are different ways of understanding the verse. Or maybe the Talmud agrees that the on the surface level it means appointed, but is teaching an extra layer of meaning.

Comment: I am in total agreement in regards to "extra layer of meaning". I just wanted to have the rabbinical source for "hidden".